# Present Sheet in a center of parent window

Tags: swift, macos, xamarin

I use function

```
NSViewController.PresentViewControllerAsSheet(NSViewController)
```

and everything works great, but I would like to have a chance change the position of this sheet (for ex. in the center of parent).

How to do that ?

Comment: Apple's docs say to use `func presentAsSheet(_ viewController: NSViewController)`, unless you want to use a custom animator.

Comment: Yes, I do this using func presentAsSheet but at the end I get something similar to this image: http://www.nickkuh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/OSX-Document-Modal-Dialogs-Sheets-640x516.png

and I would like to change position of this sheet

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found solution:

C# code, Xamarin.Mac

```
controller.PresentViewControllerAsModalWindow(_settingsController);

if (_settingsController.View.Window != null)
{
    var x = (_window.Frame.Left) + (_window.Frame.Width / 2) - 400;
    var y = (_window.Frame.Top) + (_window.Frame.Height / 2) - 300;
    _settingsController.View.Window.SetFrame(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x, y, 800, 600), true);
    _settingsController.View.Window.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
    _settingsController.View.Window.TitlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
    _settingsController.View.Window.StyleMask = NSWindowStyle.FullSizeContentView | NSWindowStyle.Borderless;
    _settingsController.View.Window.IsMovable = false;
}
```